# Standard method for MySQL's IF() function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have found [MySQL's IF() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to be very useful in giving me an efficient way to do conditional aggregate functions, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`something`='a', `something_weight`, 0)) AS `A`, SUM(`something_weight`) AS `All` FROM...
```

It is my understanding that this function is a feature of MySQL, and is not generally available in databases that use SQL.

Is there a more standard method to achieve this functionality on the database side of things?

Comment: See here for more examples: https://janac.medium.com/if-statements-in-mysql-conditional-logic-7e5acab4e8a8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a sql guru but case statement

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

might be standard ansi.

Answer (score 2):

I believe using a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement would be more standard.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE `something` WHEN 'a' THEN `something_weight` ELSE 0 END) AS `A`, 
       SUM(`something_weight`) AS `All` 
    FROM...
```

Answer (score 2):

CASE is the general command you can use to do conditional aggregate functions.  For more info see http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL you can do this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE something WHEN 'a' THEN something_weight ELSE 0 END) as [a],
       SUM(something_weight) as [All]
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

look at using CASE: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN something='a' THEN XXX
                WHEN something='b' THEN YYY
                ELSE 0
                END
          ) AS ColumnName