# SQL MAX() omitting values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, max

I have a table with a column "version"
It specifies software version with a string "3.2.2.0" for example
It can have too the "DEBUG" version

I want to obtain the MAX value of the column, but omitting DEBUG, 
DEBUG only shown if is the only value

Examples:

```
Version
-------
3.2.0
3.2.0
DEBUG
3.2.1
3.2.2

MAX(version) 
result obtained -> DEBUG
result desired -> 3.2.2

Version
-------
DEBUG
DEBUG
DEBUG

MAX(version) 
result -> DEBUG  OK!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only touches the table once. It is *this* simple...

```
...
CASE
   WHEN MIN(Version) = 'DEBUG' THEN 'DEBUG'
   ELSE MAX(NULLIF(Version, 'DEBUG'))
END AS Version
...
```

Original, before update:

```
...
MAX(CASE WHEN Version = 'DEBUG' THEN '' ELSE Version END)
...
```

Comment: @Bohemian: why? Prove it. Edit: MySQL and SQL Server examples on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5143460/27535

Comment: elegant use of of CASE, but it won't ever return 'DEBUG' even in the second case mentioned when DEBUG would be the correct result.

Comment: @Ray: ah, missed that bit. Will correct. Thanks for explaining what I'd missed, unlike some folk...

Answer (score 3):

```
select max(version)
from my_table
where version != 'DEBUG'
union
select max(version)
from my_table
where not exists (select * from my_table where version != 'DEBUG');
```

Or if you're using mysql:

```
select ifnull(max(version), 'DEBUG')
from my_table
where version != 'DEBUG'
```

and for postgres:

```
select coalesce(max(version), 'DEBUG')
from my_table
where version != 'DEBUG'
```

Comment: You're seriously suggesting 3 touches on the table when a simple CASE will suffice?

Comment: Your will always have one row with value `null` in your first version. Postgres version works fine in SQL Server as well.