# Is there a function in MonetDB that is equivalent to IF?

Tags: sql, monetdb

I need to do something like this in MonetDB:

```
select
  If(value > 0, value, -1) as selected_value
from
  table
```

In mysql, this means 'return value if value > 0, otherwise return -1.'
Is there an equivalent function to this in MonetDB?

And I am not looking for a case statement. I know it exists in both MonetDB and other sql languages. I would like specifically to know of something like the example I gave.

Thank you

Comment: I have never worked with MonetDB but standard SQL syntax for that would be `SELECT CASE WHEN Value>0 THEN Value ELSE -1 END AS SelectedValue FROM table` which should be supported according to MonetDB documentation

Comment: @NenadZivkovic In that case is possible to do concatenations? For example:
`case when value> 0 then value else -1 end || case when value < 0 then 5 else 0 end` (assume everything's varchars for concatenations)

Comment: While I guess it's possible, I have no idea what this example is suppose to do :) Can you update your question with example and expected result?

Comment: It is possible, I tested it. However, my question was meant to avoid using case statements. The 'If' function is really what I was looking for.

Comment: are you actually looking for the sql `WHERE` clause?  the example you've provided above can be easily solved with case statements like..  `CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN value WHEN value < 0 THEN 5 ELSE -1 END`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know **there isn't an equivalent function to this in MonetDB**.

[The if() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) is part of the [MySQL Extensions to Standard SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/extensions-to-ansi.html), but this extension in not part of the [monet builtin function](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/BuiltinFunctions)

Like many other SQL database also in **monetdb** is not available 
an ´IF()´ function because isn't part of the standard SQL language.

For other evidence see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5143460/1657028) and try your query in a [standard parser](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml#parser).

I'm am aware that you are not looking for a case **statement**, howsoever , according to [SQL in a Nutshell](http://users.atw.hu/sqlnut/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-4.html): **ANSI SQL2003 provides a function named CASE]** that can be used to create **IF-THEN flow-control logic** within queries or update statements.

The CASE function provides IF-THEN-ELSE functionality within a **SELECT or UPDATE statement**. It evaluates a list of conditions and returns one value out of several possible values.

CASE has two usages: simple and searched. Simple CASE expressions compares one value, the input_value, with a list of other values and return a result associated with the first matching value. Searched CASE expressions allow the analysis of several logical conditions and return a result associated with the first one that is true.

[monetdb supported features](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Features/Supported) includes:

- F261: CASE expression
- F261-01: Simple CASE
- F261-02: Searched CASE

Therefore , in my opinion, the best chance is to code a ´Boolean searched operation´ is:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN value ELSE -1 END AS selected_value
FROM
  table;
```

Furthermore
[The monetdb dcumentation about flowcontrol](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/Flowofcontrol) reports that it allows both ´CASE WHEN´ and ´IF THEN ELSE´and the SQL standard allows to create SQL functions and [MonetDB has this support](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Functions).

I think ,but I don't encourage and not tested, that you might define your own function; something like that:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION MY_CONV(value int)
 RETURNS int
 BEGIN
    IF (value > 0)
        THEN RETURN value
        ELSE RETURN -1;
    END IF;
 END;
```

hence

```
 SELECT MY_CONV(value) FROM table;
```

Even  more complicated could be try to code a [UserDefinedFunction](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/UserDefinedFunction)